# media queries max width not working on breakpoint in Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries, microsoft-edge, mozilla

My HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

My CSS:

```
    div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: yellow;
    }

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        div {
            background: blue;
        }
    }
```

If you resize screen to width exactly 767px in Chrome or Firefox the color is still yellow! only when you move to 766px or less the color changes to blue. Is this a bug in Chrome and Firefox?

Here's codepen: [link](https://codepen.io/CodingToBeWithHer/pen/WXJVYp)

please help

edit: image attached:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYNjz.png)

Comment: Your Codepen works as expected in Chrome for me (on a Mac, if that makes a difference): blue at 767, yellow at 768.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've just checked, on Mac is working fine, the problem is on Windows in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using the CodePen, in neither Linux nor Windows, sorry. Do you have your browser zoomed in our out, so that the width the CodePen shows may have rounding errors?

Comment: I have Chrome version: 62.0.3202.94 and machine on 64bit. I have my zoom set at 100% and didn't change it ever

Comment: Are you sure you cannot reproduce the problem ? I have just checked on a different machine with different windows and Chrome version and the problem also exists

Comment: This is working fine to me. Chrome  62.0.3202.94 on Windows 10

Comment: Could you post me an print screen with the square being blue for you at 767px please ? I will add my screenshot in the question in 1 min

Comment: I have attached the screenshot, you can see 767px and colour still yellow, and I've checked on entirely different machine and there is the same problem! Also I checked that when I go to external websites that use max-width on all of them at exactly 767px in Chrome the css with max-width 767px is not applied, but at 766px is applied

Comment: why downvote? the desired behaviour is obviously that the css inside (max-width: 767px) should be applied at 767px also.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem in Chrome or Firefox, too.

Comment: could you go to my pencode, resize the screen to exactly 767px and do a printscreen that the color is actually blue? Like the image I have attached

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/iYwkB

Comment: you have resized to 698px not to 767px as I asked. I said that the problem is when the screen width is EXACTLY 767px.

Comment: The width of the viewport in your screenshot is 928 pixels wide. Compare yours to [my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY6gC.png).

Answer (score 0):

Came here because I was having the same issue. Mr. Lister has the right idea. Even if your browser isn't zoomed, there's a display setting in Windows commonly used in laptops called "Change the size of text, apps, and other items". The recommend setting on my machine was 125%, which screws a few things up.

If you change this setting to 100% it should fix your issue. Also try calling the following in the console, you should get 766.

```
window.innerWidth;
```